# session var lost while switching pages & session_save_path saving an empty file

Tags: php, session, session-variables, superglobals

I have made an HomePage in which there i place two buttons "VISIT SHOP"  and "SHOP NOW" when i press "SHOP NOW" button, a login form div sets to

```
   display:block
```

when I enter username and password in that form and press login button it's form action links me to again HomePage but this time some changes appear in homepage and the session_starts and all the username and password variables values stored in session variable such as

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

Now when i press "VISIT SHOP" button it links me to the `Electronic-Gadgets1.php` and there i `echo` session variable e.g

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo $_SESSION['password'];
```

but It says `"Notice: Undefined variable: _Session in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\inner\Electronic-Gadgets1.php"`

I have read so many posts, messages, comments, and asks teachers and around 1 day of full searching for my problem but i still can't find my problem.

and I have also look for Session.save_path my path is set
but the problem is that it makes file on that path but when
I open It I found It empty file.

If You guys want me to attach code I'll provide
but please guys I am seriously very annoyed and I 
don't know how I complete my project By Wednesday
It's frustrating me.

Comment: First of all, the superglobal is named $_SESSION (not ucfirst'ed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reference `$_SESSION`, not `$_Session`. PHP variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Oh yes thats my fault let I check whether it's running or not